# Javascript - Reversing every string of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reverse

I'm working on an exercise and **I can't use** any kind of Array.prototype.reverse or Array.prototype.join. I have to reverse every string in an array individually and print them on separate lines.

Here is what I've tried :

```
// Create a function that reverses elements of a string

let reversedStuff = function (str) {
  let newReversed = "";
  for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newReversed += str[i];
  }
  return newReversed;
};


// Use the previous function to apply the reverse on each string of an array

const args = process.argv.slice(2);
let allArr = [];
let eachWord = function (args) {
  for (let y = 0; y <= args.length; y++) {
    return functionReverse(args)
  }
};
console.log(eachWord(args));
```

The problem is with my first function. I can't quietly fins a way to apply the reverse function on every string of an array, it only applies on the first one. Any tips on how to approach this problem?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `y <= args.length` should be `<`, and just `allArr.push(reversedStuff(args[y]));` then at the end `return allArr;`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your second function:

1. You are passing the entire array into `functionReverse` instead of the element. Pass the element `args[y]` instead, like this: `functionReverse(args[y])`. Also, you probably meant to call `reversedStuff` instead of `functionReverse`.
2. The loop condition should be `y < args.length` as arrays are zero-indexed.
3. The return statement ends the for loop after the first iteration because return exits the function. Instead, you should define the array within the function and then return the array at the end:

```
let eachWord = function (args) {
   let allArr = [];
   for (let y = 0; y <= args.length; y++) {
     allArr.push(reversedStuff(args[y]));
   }
   return allArr;
};
console.log(eachWord(args));
```

---

A nicer/more idiomatic solution would be to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of a loop:

```
let eachWord = function (args) {
   return args.map(reversedStuff);
};
console.log(eachWord(args));
```

`map` returns a new array where each element is the result of applying the given function to each element in the source array.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `reverseStuff(args[y])` in your code instead of `return functionReverse(args)`? Because, the first one will call the reverse function for each string. The second one will probably be an error since there is no function named functionReverse in your code. Even if it existed, what you are doing is calling that function with the entire array of strings every time for the length of the array args. The missing `args[y]` is the main issue. Here, you are accessing the value at the yth index of the array args which, is what you wanted to do. Also, as @ASDFGerte pointed out, `<=` should be `<` since the first one will return `undefined`.

Also note that with the above change, the function will iterate through the array but since it returns nothing, the `console.log(eachword(args))` line will print undefined. In this case, you can do the following:

```
// inside the for loop in eachWord
console.log(reverseStuff(args[y]);
```

Or, the better solution will be the following:

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
let allArr = [];
let eachWord = function (args, cb) {
  for (let y = 0; y < args.length; y++) {
      cb(reverseStuff(args[y]));
  }
};
let cb = function(reveredString) {
    // do what you want here
    // for example
    allArr.push(reveredString);
    // or just simply print
    console.log(reversedString);
};
eachWord(args, cb);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The second solution mutates a global array in the `cb` function which makes things confusing :P I think the best way to do it is using `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: @Nathan You're right and it is confusing to mutate a global array inside a callback. However, it is also at the same time a more flexible solution where eachWord acts like a simple iterator and applies any given function on the strings. `[].prototype.map` is the best solution as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler solution - use the below function

```js
    function reverseArray(arr) {
       for(let idx in arr) { 
         arr[idx] = arr[idx].split('').reverse().join('');
       }
    }
    
    const sampleArr = ['ABC', 'DEF','GHI','JKL'];
    
    console.log('Before Reverse', sampleArr);
    
    reverseArray(sampleArr);
    
    console.log('After Reverse', sampleArr);
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want to change the existing array use below function

```js
        function reverseArray(arr) {
           return arr.map(item => item.split('').reverse().join(''));
        }
        
        const sampleArr = ['ABC', 'DEF','GHI','JKL'];
        const reverseArr = reverseArray(sampleArr);
        console.log('Before Reverse', sampleArr);
        console.log('After Reverse', reverseArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! I ended up ending with something like this :

```
const revereString = function () {
  const args = process.argv.slice(2);
  let result = '';
  // First loop that look into each string in the array
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    let str = '';
    // Second loop that look into each letters of each string, and reverse them
    for (let j = args[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      str += args[i][j];
    }
    // Printing each reversed string on their own line, until the last string of an array.
    result += str;
    if (i !== args.length - 1) {
      result += str + '\n';
    }

  }
  return result;
};

console.log(revereString());
```

I couldn't use .reverse or .join for this exercice but I still take note of your advices. They make it look so easy!